Handle invalid variable name error in bash indirect references
Take a look at this simple example:
x="foo bar"
echo ${!x}

It erros: -bash: foo bar: invalid variable name.
I'm writing a script where a positional argument will indicate a "color name" and we use indirect references to fetch the hex code of the color name. I want the script to keep going if the user passes a color name with space in it or generally an invalid color name (which we will default to white).
I also tried this try/catch approach but to no avail:
x="foo bar"
echo ${!x} || echo error

The closes thing I could find was this, but didn't help:
Bash reference variable by string name

As you are using bash, how about switching to an array?

@pmf I could use an associative array, but I thought, gathering from the last link in the question, there should be a syntax to handle this issue in indirect references? Or maybe the developers really didn't consider this use case?

Indirect expansion is only good for internal use. If you're taking a variable name from the user it's on you to validate it.

@Shayan If you MUST use indirection, you could abuse declare for that, e.g. declare -- "${x}" 2>/dev/null || echo error

@pmf I'm amazed how this works! Would you please write an answer? Thank you!

It certainly was considered -- these names are explicitly illegal by specification. An associative array would avoid the issue -- key names are allowed to have spaces.

BTW, I'd strongly suggest declare -p instead of declare -- -- otherwise too much chance of that user input being something that has side effects when run.

you code snippets mention x='foo bar' while the description mentions processing colors; recommend you rewrite the question to focus on your actual (color) issue: a) show the setup of a couple colors, b) show your code working for a valid color and c) show your code's result with an invalid color (ie, show all stdout/stderr output); net result: provide a minimal reproducible example

This may be the error handling you need :
test -v "$x" || echo error

